# How to get buttons to interact with text boxes

Tags: app-inventor

I am creating a fitness calculator app, and when I try to get the buttons to interact with the text boxes I either get an error or it just won't connect. I mean when you click the button it should fill in the respected text box, but nothing works. Please help.

Comment: you should elaborate on your question and include the code examples so that others can direct based on what you have done

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might want to edit your question and add a screenshot of your **relevant** blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that the block you're trying to place isnt compatible, try use button:onClick and make a label and update it with that ?

I think this is what you're aiming for, or along those lines, your question is quite vague

[Screencap of button updating label from input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llSTP.png)